# Unable to assign values to a pandas data frame column from a list suing iteration

Tags: python-3.x, list, pandas

I am changing my original code, to present a much simplified version of it. But, this is where the main problem is occurring.
Using the following code:

```
Sp=pd.DataFrame()
l1=['a', 'b', 'c']
for i in l1:
    Sp['col1'] = i
```

Gives me the result Sp as:

```
col1
```

I would want my col1 to have values a, b and c. Could anyone please suggest why this is happening, and how to rectify it.

EDIT:

For every value in my list, I use it to connect to a different file using os, (file names are made up of list values). After picking up the csv file from there I take values such as mean, devisation etc. of the data from the file and assign those values to sp in another column. My final sp should look something as follows:

```
col1    Mean    Median  Deviation
a       1       1.1     0.5
b       2       2.1     0.5
c       3       3.1     0.5
```

Comment: @ Jezrael I am not using the loop just for assignment purpose. There are other operations too in every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: If need for each loop create `DataFrame` and processes it, iterate and final `DataFrame` append to list of DataFrames. Last [`concat`](http://pands.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) all aggregated DataFrames together:

```
dfs = []
l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for i in l1:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    df = df.groupby('col').agg({'col1':'mean', 'col2':'sum'})
    #another code
    dfs.append(df)

Sp = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Old answer:

I think need call `DataFrame` constructor with `list`:

```
Sp = pd.DataFrame({'col1':l1})
```

If really need it, but it is the [slowiest possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24871316/2901002):

> 6) **updating an empty frame a-single-row-at-a-time**. I have seen this method used WAY too much. It is by far the slowest. It is probably common place (and reasonably fast for some python structures), but a DataFrame does a fair number of checks on indexing, so this will always be very slow to update a row at a time. Much better to create new structures and concat.

```
Sp=pd.DataFrame()
l1=['a', 'b', 'c']
for j, i in enumerate(l1):
    Sp.loc[j, 'col1'] = i

print (Sp)
  col1
0    a
1    b
2    c
```

Comment: Thanks. Large data set . Wouldn't want it to slow down. Any other way to still use the loop?

Comment: @A.DS - Loops is necessary? Can you explain more?

Comment: Use [assign][1] which assigns new columns to a DataFrame, returning a new object (a copy) with the new columns added to the original ones as shown below -

    Sp = Sp.assign( col1 = l1 )


  [1]: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html

Comment: For every value in my list, I use it to connect to a different file using os. After picking up the csv file from there I take values such as mean, devisation etc. of the data from the file and assign those values to sp in another column.

Comment: @A.DS - I think I understand, please check edited answer.